# mod_rewrite redirect url if no file found to main page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to be able to Access my scripts without the .php, .html etc., so I already wrote

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
##same for other extensions
```

in my .htaccess file (note: this file lies not in the root-path), but I also want to Redirect every incorrect request to my main page, so that www.mysite.com/dir/incorrect will be rewritten to www.mysite.com/dir/.

But my first try (RewriteRule ^ / [R] after RewriteCond) redirected me to www.mysite.com/, my experiments with RewriteBase (RewriteBase . and RewriteBase /) didnt work and I also noticed that many similar scriptredirect to www.mysite.com/dir/index.php (www.mysite.com/dir/index in my case), but I really want to Redirect to www.mysite.com/dir/. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on

# see if .php is found
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

# determine DIR_BASE dynamically
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=DIR_BASE:%1]

# if not found redirect to %{ENV:DIR_BASE}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:DIR_BASE} [L,R]
```

Comment: thanks, but i have still the Problem that RewriteRule ^ / [L, R] Redirects to www.mysite.com/ instead of www.mysite.com/dir/ (/dir is the Directory where the .htaccess file is)

Comment: Oh that can also be done but it wasn't mentioned in the question. I will update the answer in few minutes.

Comment: thank you very much, that questions made me mad for the last days, thanks for the answer